# heroku run rake db:migrate を実行すると relation does not exist というエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

herokuでデプロイまではできたのですが、heroku run rake db:migrateをすると
エラーがでてしまいます。
昨夜から色々やってみたのですが、どうにもわかりません

6行目はActiveAdmin.routes(self)

> devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
>     ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

#### git push heroku master

```
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> (none)
remote:        Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, web, worker
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 45.8MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v6
remote:        https://afternoon-caverns-3384.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy.... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/afternoon-caverns-1543.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

#### heroku run rake db:migrate

```
hogehoge-no-MacBook-Air:jaco-ver4.0.0 hoge$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.6083
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "items" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"items"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"items"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum

rake aborted!
ActiveAdmin::DatabaseHitDuringLoad: Your file, app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb (line 822), caused a database error while Active Admin was loading. This is most common when your database is missing or doesn't have the latest migrations applied. To prevent this error, move the code to a place where it will only be run when a page is rendered. One solution can be, to wrap the query in a Proc.Original error message: PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "items" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"items"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"items"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-7e72b7881eb6/lib/active_admin/error.rb:43:in `rescue in capture'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-7e72b7881eb6/lib/active_admin/error.rb:41:in `capture'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-7e72b7881eb6/lib/active_admin/application.rb:203:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-7e72b7881eb6/lib/active_admin/application.rb:195:in `block in load!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-7e72b7881eb6/lib/active_admin/application.rb:195:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-7e72b7881eb6/lib/active_admin/application.rb:195:in `load!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-7e72b7881eb6/lib/active_admin/application.rb:217:in `routes'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-7e72b7881eb6/lib/active_admin.rb:78:in `routes'
/app/config/routes.rb:6:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in `eval_block'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:315:in `draw'
/app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:71:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:389:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

エラーメッセージを見るに、ActiveAdminがMigration実行前にテーブルを読みにいっているようですね。
ネットでも同じようなエラー報告がいくつか挙がっていました。

スタックトレースを見ると

```
/app/config/routes.rb:6:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

とあるので、`routes.rb`の6行目で何かしらActiveAdminが動き始める処理が書かれているようです。

なので`routes.rb`の6行目前後も追記してください。

あと、ActiveAdminが関連しそうなコードをいったんコメントアウトしろ、みたいな回答もあります。

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20322552/1058763

具体的にどこになるのかはアプリによって異なると思いますが、ActiveAdminが自動的に呼び出されそうな処理はいったんコメントアウトすると良いかもしれません。

### EDIT

追記ありがとうございます。
追記はしてもらったんですが、僕自身はActiveAdminを触ったことがないのでこのコードが何をやっているのかよくわからなかったりします ^^;

当てずっぽうな回答ですいませんが、以下のような作業を試してみてください。

1. 6行目をコメントアウトしてコミット（できれば5行目も？ActiveAdminの名が付いている箇所は怪しいです）
2. Herokuにデプロイ
3. Herokuでdb:migrate （ここでmigrateが成功することを期待）
4. 1でコメントアウトしたところを元に戻す。
5. Herokuにデプロイ
6. Herokuで動作確認

Comment: routes.rbの6行目を追記しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事にmigrateできました。
そして新たに複数の問題が見つかりましたが、それでも嬉しいです。
ちゃんと動いています！

Answer (score 2):

以下のコマンドを実行してから、再度、`heroku run rake db:migrate` を実行してみては、どうでしょう？

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE
```